# Spline Chart with shadow or 3D Spline Chart or Cubic Line Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am using MPAndroidChart library for a project of mine to integrate charts in my app. I know how to use LineCharts but I couldn't figure out a way to use the graph in the image feature of the LineCharts. The image below shows the kind of graph i want.

[look at the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljBWR.png)